# Problem with rewrite

Tags: coq

I've just started with Coq and I don't understand why it does not accept `rewrite` in the next situation. The following exercise is from "Coq in hurry":
Define `add` as:

```
Fixpoint add n m := match n with 0 => m | S p => add p ( S m) end.
```

The exercise is:

```
forall n m, add n ( S m) = S ( add n m)
```

I was able to prove it but with a rather long solution. My second attempt, where the problem arises, was as follows:

```
Lemma addlemma1 : forall n m, add n ( S m) = S ( add n m).
Proof.
induction n.
intros m.
simpl.
reflexivity.
```

At this point I'd like to use `rewrite IHn` but it doesn't work. Looking at the solution in the book, it is the following:

```
Lemma addlemma1 : forall n m, add n ( S m) = S ( add n m).
Proof.
induction n; intros m; simpl.
reflexivity.
rewrite IHn; reflexivity.
Qed.
```

This runs correctly. To me it looks like my attempt is the same as the solution, but I don't understand why in one case rewrite works and the other does not. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Semicolon `;` and period `.` have different meanings in Coq proof. So, while your solution looks similar to the given solution, they are not the same: `;` performs tactics in parallel and `.` in series.

For your solution:

```ml
Lemma addlemma1 : forall n m, add n ( S m) = S ( add n m).
Proof.
induction n.
intros m.
simpl.
reflexivity.
```

If you read the goal at this point, it should be something like:

```ml
1 goal

goal 1 (ID 22) is:
 forall m : nat, add (S n) (S m) = S (add (S n) m)
```

But the goal doesn't meet the "shape" that `IHn` expects.

So, to complete your solution, you need to repeat the `intros m. simpl.` tactics:

```ml
Lemma addlemma1 : forall n m, add n ( S m) = S ( add n m).
Proof.
  induction n.
  - (* when n = 0 *)
    intros m.
    simpl.
    reflexivity.
  - (* when n = S n *)
    intros m.
    simpl.
    rewrite IHn.
    reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Note: I prefer using `-` for each subgoal.